# Why was my javascript code not accepted at interview?

Tags: javascript

The interviewer told me that I have to follow javascript "patterns" and write "clean code". He also said that I should follow the prototype pattern. Here is my code sample:

```
//namespace declrations
var MyNamespace = {};
MyNamespace.UCs = {};
MyNamespace.Pages = {};
//function declarations
MyNamespace.UCs.test = function () { alert('this is a test function in user control namespace.'); }
MyNamespace.Pages.test = function () { alert('this is a test function in web page namespace.'); }
```

So can anybody point me to why this code is not ok? I mean, I have declared namespaces first and then added my members and functions like the above sample. So does it really have issues or am I missing something?

Comment: this should really be on the code review site, but that's not listed in the alternate site list...

Comment: Here's a good source for javascript patterns http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/

Comment: What were the requirements? The code is very hard to judge without the actual requirements from interviewer. I mean I doubt he just asked you to write a bunch of object literals.

Comment: Ahh, you answered before I finished my post.  But there is a large read at the bottom if you want it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well when you are writing code in a large environment, lots of problems can start happening.  So it's important to separate your class definitions from how you use those classes.  Which also means you have to make classes that can be unit tested to prove that they do what you say they do.  Javascript is not a true object orientated language and as such there are several ways to "fake" it.  But because the language has a lot of flexibility, we can duplicate some approaches.

One thing we want to stay away from is something called function scope simply because it can cause unintended "features" later down the road when 3 or 4 other programmers start making assumptions about what your code is doing. If they don't know a global variable was overwritten one or two function closures ago, it will make finding that problem more difficult.  So I would suggest using a small class created by [John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/) as it provides a very simple approach that gives you alot of the functionality you need.

So let's write some code.

```
 var myNamespace = myNamespace || { }

 /**
   * Used to store a single entry in the log
   *
   * @class
   */
 var myNamespace.LogEntry = Class.extend({

     /**
       * Used to track the beginning of the page load
       *
       * @private
       * @static
       */
     PAGE_LOAD_TIME = new Date().getTime(),

     /**
       * Used to store the current time
       * 
       * @type int
       */
     time : undefined,

     /**
       * The message of this log entry
       *
       * @type string
       */
     msg : undefined,

     /**
       * @constructor
       * 
       * @param {string} msg The message of this log entry
       */
     init : function (msg) {
         this.time = new Date().getTime() - this.PAGE_LOAD_TIME;
         this.msg = msg
     },

     /**
       * Displays this log entry in a single string
       *
       * @return {string} String representation of this log entry
       */
     toString : function () {
         return this.time + ": " + this.msg;
     }
 });

 /**
   * Used to store a log entry that has data associated with it.
   *
   * @class
   * @extends myNamespace.LogEntry
   */
 var myNamespace.DataEntry = myNamespace.LogEntry.extend({

     /**
       * Used to store data associated with this log entry
       *
       * @type object
       */
     data : undefined,

     /**
       * @constructor
       *
       * @param {string} msg The message that describes this log entry
       * @param {object} data The data associated with this entry
       */
     init : function (msg, data) {
          this._super(msg);
          this.data = data;
     },

     /**
       * @return {string} The string representation of this log entry
       */
     toString : function () {
          // Uses a JSON library to stringify the data into a json string.
          return this._super() + JSON.stringify(this.data);
     }
 });

 /**
   * Provides an interface to log messages
   *
   * @class
   */
 var myNamespace.Log = Class.extend({

     /**
       * Stores log entries
       *
       * @type myNamespace.LogEntry[]
       */
     log : undefined,

     /**
       * @constructor
       */
     init : function () {
         this.log = [ ];
     },

     /**
       * Logs a message into the log
       *
       * @param {string} msg The message you want to log
       */
     msg : function (msg) {
         this.log.push(new myNamespace.LogEntry(msg));
     },

     /**
       * Log a message and data into the log
       *
       * @param {string} msg The message of this log entry
       * @param {object} data The data associated with this log entry
       */
     data : function(msg, data) {
         this.log.push(new myNamespace.DataEntry(msg, data));
     }

 });
```

Ok, there is lots of stuff going on here.  The main part is that this is all definitions of classes.  I don't actually use anything up there.  The program only stores the current time in LogEntry.PAGE_LOAD_START which is declared @static so the behavior will be expected.  I've used lots of jsDocs here to make everything clear about what the intentions are.  A program like intelliJ can use those to give your code feedback if you aren't using the classes the way you've documentated them.

This program will let you create and store log entries with possibly logging data.  There are alot of other ways to do this.  I declare everything before the constructor instead of inside the constructor so that I can document the types and whether they are private.

A programmer that has to use the log will know exactly how to use it and if they want to create or extend these classes, they can do so without unintended effects from function closure.

Here's how to use it:

```
 var anotherNamespace = anotherNamespace || {};

 var anotherNamespace = new myNamespace.Log();

 ...

 anotherNamespace.log.msg("This is a test");

 ...

 anotherNamespace.log.data("Test msg with data", data);
```

Of course the obvious thing missing here is a way to display all the data.  But that could be in another class that iterates through the Log.log array and spits out the toString() into a web page or file.  The point here is that the classes and their functions are simple, unit testable, and definition only.

Comment: thanks for the answer. i can see alot of difference in your code and the code Ivo Wetzel send to us so which one is the standard and a better way to define namespaces and classes?

Comment: Well in my opinion mine has quite a few advantages.  Most obvious of which is that you can extend the classes in my example.  The comment about "all those assignment wasting lines" that Wetzel made is missing the point of those lines.  Readability always always trumps optimization.  The code I've written above is reusable, extendable and readable.  All extremely important in professional software development where you aren't the only hands in the source code.

Comment: but isn't this statement: var myNamespace.LogEntry = Class.extend({}); is equal to: var myNamespace.LogEntry = function() {}; and var myNamespace.DataEntry = myNamespace.LogEntry.extend({}); is actually equal to: var myNamespace.LogEntry.prototype.DataEntry = new function(){};

Comment: No, though you may be right.  DataEntry = LogEntry.extend() makes it obvious that the DataEntry is an extenstion of LogEntry.  It means that the DataEntry has all the methods of LogEntry and can call it's super class(LogEntry) internally by using this._super() in an overrideing method.  It also says that DataEntry can be used everywhere that LogEntry can be used and not cause any problems.  It also means that anyone that wants to use the Log class can use either LogEntry or DataEntry interchangeable whenever they want.

Comment: What's a "true object oriented language"?

Answer (score 1):

FIrst of all, make use of object literals, all those assignments are a waste lines.

Second, you don't have the prototype "pattern" implemented anywhere, also I'd go for some encapsulation if you have full control over the namespaces:

```
(function() { // anonymous wrapper

    function Foo(a) { // i can haz prototype "Pattern"
        this.memberVal = a;
    }

    Foo.prototype = {

        someMethod: function(value) {
            console.log(value, this.memberVal);
        },

        yam: function() {

        }

    };

    // Let's assume we have full control here, otherwise Alnitak's answer is fine too.
    window.namespace = {

        test: {
            Foo: Foo
        }

    };

})();

var test = new namespace.test.Foo(123);
test.someMethod('bla');
```

Comment: aha! i guess we found what the interviewer meant! but isn't this a little complex?

Comment: that depends on what the interviewer's expectations were. In my opinion it isn't complex, it's just one of the ways it must be done.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the interviewer literally meant you should be using the 'namespace' method?

Tutorial with example of usage:
http://elegantcode.com/2011/01/26/basic-javascript-part-8-namespaces/

Comment: I think actually the point is this line "MyNamespace.UCs.test" - I think the employer wanted "MyNamespace.UCs.prototype.test" which is different. Using the .prototype is closer to class definition in langauges like c# etc

Comment: @jim It doesn't sound like he meant that, it's not a "standard" method after all.

Comment: @PaulSullivan that only makes sense if `MyNamespace.UCs` is a function.  In the OP's code it's clearly a nested namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks (mostly) fine, if the intent was to just put utility functions in a shared namespace, without any object orientation or data encapsulation.

I would have made *one* change, on the initial name space declarations:

```
var MyNamespace = MyNamespace || {};
MyNamespace.UCs = MyNamespace.UCs || {};
MyNamespace.Pages = Mynamespace.Pages || {};
```

to ensure that the code didn't obliterate any existing methods in those namespaces.

Comment: "intent was to just put utility functions in a shared namespace, without any object orientation or data encapsulation" and what if i want to do exacly object orientation or data encapsulation? how my code would change according to that?

Comment: @jim if e.g. `MyNamespace.Pages.Counter = function() { ... }` where `Counter` is a "class" you can add methods to it by adding stuff to `MyNamespace.Pages.Counter.prototype`.

Comment: nice! i was trying to centeralize my javascript code for the website. so UCs will contain functions that are called from my user controls and Pages will contain the functions that are called from my web pages.